# Maximum hole size to stop a fluid passing through a solid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

In a [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47021/how-to-find-out-the-maximum-radius-of-a-hole-that-can-keep-water-stay-in-a-conta), the following is answered in a general sense:

> Assume I have a inverse cone which holds 200ml water. I am going to cut the tip of the cone to create a small hole. How to calculate the maximum radius of the hole that the water will still stay in the container ?

However, what is not clear to me is whether the material of the vessel matters. The surface tension of water IN AIR is used in the answer $\left(\gamma \approx 7.3{\times}{10}^{-2}\,\frac{\mathrm{N}}{\mathrm{m}}\right)$; however, I would think the surface tension and contact angle between the water and the cup have an effect.

For example, if I have a one cone cup that is hydrophobic and one cone cup that is hydrophilic, will the hole size necessary to stop the water dripping out be the exact same?

Comment: The shape of the cone will also matter.  Tall and thin cones will hold water that is "deeper" than short and shallow cones.  The water pressure at the bottom of the cone will vary depending on the shape of the cone.

Comment: Yes materials do matter. Both the cone material and the liquid it holds. Google *surface energy*

Comment: External disturbances (vibration or impulse) also matter.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding overcoming the Laplace pressure $\delta p$ is the only that matters if not disturbed.
$$\delta p = \gamma \cdot \left(\frac{1}{R_x} + \frac{1}{R_y} \right)$$  Where Rx and Ry are radii for a droplet in x,y direction $\gamma$ is surface tension for a liquid at specified circumstances (e.g. temperature). For water at approximately 20 Celsius degrees it is $0.075 \frac{\mathrm{N}}{\mathrm{m}}$.
The pressure build up  $\rho g h$ and $\frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R} =$ diameter for round droplets (and hole)
$ p > \delta p$ make the droplet grow bigger than $d$ on outside the hole 
$ \rho g h > \gamma \frac{1}{d} \Rightarrow \rho g h d > \gamma$ make droplet to fall.

Example: Water $\gamma = 0.075 \frac{\mathrm{N}}{\mathrm{m}}$ hole $d = 0.1 \, \mathrm{mm} = 0.0001 \, \mathrm{m}$ in hydrophobic material$$
\Rightarrow h > \frac{\gamma}{\rho g d} = \frac{0.075 \frac{\mathrm{N}}{\mathrm{m}}}{1000 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{{\mathrm{m}}^3} 9.81 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{{\mathrm{s}}^2} 0.0001 \, \mathrm{m}} = 0.076 \, \mathrm{m}
\,.$$This means that at water level $7.6 \, \mathrm{cm} \, \left(\approx 3"\right)$ and upwards the drops will fall though a $0.1 \, \mathrm{mm}$ hole in hydrophobic material. Hydrophilic materials make droplets to the outer edge of material and the diameter is measured from there. This means that a hole on a hydrophilic surface will leak through very small holes. Tested with an approximately 1 mm hole seems to be a close estimation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension

Answer (score 0):

The vessel do matters. But you can only loose. If you look the [capillarity from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action#Height_of_a_meniscus), you can notice that the contact angle has an influence in the height of a liquid column. But the equation reveals you, that the influence is $\cos\left(\theta_{\text{contact}}\right)$, and it's a plain multiplier. $\cos\left(0\right)$ is the maximum.

You will have an effect if you use various materials; you will need even a smaller hole. The other thing which this reveals, is that you need a straight pipe. If you cut the tip of a cone, you actually need a smaller hole than a straight pipe would require.

Comment: Re the cone/tube comment you made: that is with idealized, zero thickness vessel, is it? Otherwise one could decide what kind of hole (upside-down conical, e.g.)

Comment: @bukwyrm It's quite a while I answered this. But if you turn your thoughts around; say think an infinite thick vessel, you might notice that capillarity is just about a hole rounded with a surface. Whats outside that surface, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give the radius, $R$, of the cone?

Assuming it is given,
$\hspace{100px}$[image],
as shown in figure, h could be found from volume of the cone containing liquid.

$$\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 h = 200\,\mathrm{mL} ~ \to 2 \times {10} ^{-4} \, \mathrm{m}^{3}$$

So,$$
h=\frac{3 \times 2 \times {10}^{-4}}{\pi R^2} \qquad
\rho = 1000 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m}^3} \qquad
g = 9.81 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^{2}}
\,,$$and$$
p = \rho g h ~ = ~1000*9.81*h~=~ \frac{1000 \times 9.81 \times~3~\times~2 \times {10}^{-4}}{\pi R^2}
\,,$$then plug  $p$ and $\gamma$ value in force balance equation,$$
\gamma * 2 \pi r  = ~ \frac{1000\times9.81\times~3~\times~2 \times {10}^{-4}  ~\times~\pi r^2}{\pi R^2}
\,,$$which gives the criteria$$
r  ~ \le ~  0.078 R^2
\,,$$or,$$
\frac{r}{R^2}~ \le ~ 0.078 \, {\mathrm{m}}^{-1}
\,.$$

Assumptions:

1. droplet is half-sphere;
2. volume is neglected;
3. applicable only for $200 \, \mathrm{mL}$ of water.