# What size hole will let air in but keep an 8"column of water from leaking out?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I have a 8 inch tall sports bottle into which I would like to make an air vent but not have the bottle leak when tipped up. What size hole would accomplish that?

Comment: I liked this related YouTube video [_Air Pressure and Bottle_](https://youtu.be/SvnuqkUj1Lo). I first thought this would be about molecule size and stuff, but this seems to suggest a relatively big hole. (I guess you're not supposed to shake the bottle.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the maximum radius of a hole that can keep water stay in a container by water viscosity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47021/)