# Smallest Aperture for $HCl$ to pass through

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, surface-tension, chemical-compounds

What is the smallest aperture that hydrochloric acid could pass through, such that the acid's surface tension wouldn't be stopping it from flowing through? Also, how would I work that out? I'm testing different shapes for antacid tablets and was thinking It might be interesting to test a torus because of its large surface area but am unsure of whether the $HCl$ will be able to pass through the hole or whether it will be restricted as a result of surface tension. I'm also interested in doing a similar calculation for a cube with holes drilled into each face.

Comment: Would this be better suited for [chemistry.se]?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47021/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the maximum radius of a hole that can keep water stay in a container by water viscosity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47021/)