# How to determine the maximum size of a hole that can keep ink/water stay in an ink-cartridge for fountain pens?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

What can be the maximum size of the hole? The physical forces to be taken into consideration are: external pressure, internal pressure, surface tension of the fluid (ink=water). What is the formula?
[image]

Comment: Depends on the height of the ink column.

Comment: You are right. It is a variable to implement in the formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(liquid)#Pendant%20drop%20test

Comment: It must be considered that an ink cartridge is not a tube. The bottom of the cartridge is sealed.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47021/how-to-find-out-the-maximum-radius-of-a-hole-that-can-keep-water-stay-in-a-conta

Comment: Can someone help me to adapt the expression formulated by John Rennie to my problem?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47021/how-to-find-out-the-maximum-radius-of-a-hole-that-can-keep-water-stay-in-a-conta

Comment: @MrkLch I doubt that answer is correct. The equation in that answer says that for a hole of any radius at all, there is some height of water which can be held stationary without letting it flow. Even qualitatively it is wrong. For example, the equation says that even a big hole of radius 1 cm can support about 1 mm height of water.

Comment: Damn, you're right, @Deep

Comment: Hi @Deep, can you help me with my problem? Keep in mind that the external force is of an atmosphere, the internal one is practically nothing compared, because the ink cartridge has a closed bottom! The force opposing the external pressure is practically only the surface tension of the water / ink. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MrkLch You are right. If I get at the answer I will be sure to post it.